# How to make an application license check based on receiving cookies from the user in Angular

Tags: angular, cookies, interceptor

You need to somehow check the cookies received on a successful request to identify the user's license.

Created an interceptor to test and installed the "ngx-cookie-service" package.

But I can't figure out how to write the condition correctly. Prompt knowledgeable people)

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class LicenseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req);
   }
}
```

Basically, there are solutions on the network through the JWT Token, but this option is not suitable for me, since it is used for authorization.

In my case, authorization is not required.

Comment: What do you mean JWT is used for authorization, and you don't need authorization? Strictly speaking, JWT doesn't have anything to do with authorization. It's a securely signed key-value set. That's all. Just so happens that's useful for authorization work. If you want to store a license as one of those kv's, then go ahead. Means it'll be in there and securely signed so you know it came from wherever you expect it to have come from.

Comment: Yes, that's understandable, but I need cookies to be used in this case.